# Symfony : use a 3rd-party service inside another 3rd-party bundle

Tags: php, symfony

I'm writing a 3-rd party bundle (let's call it *Bundle1*), which needs to use another 3rd-party bundle (*Bundle2*). I've declared the dependency in Bundle1's `composer.json`, so Bundle2 is successfully downloaded.

But in my AppKernel.php, i've only declared Bundle1 :

```
$bundles = [
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        [...]
        new MyCompany\Bundle1(),
    ];
```

As far as i know, It would not be correct to declare Bundle2 here. So obviously, I can't access any service provided by Bundle2 in my application. That's ok, as far as my application is concerned, but I need Bundle1 to use thoses services in its own inner classes.

How can I pass them to Bundle1, and how can I use them ? Should I declare them in Bundle1's `services.yml` and point them to Bundle2's classes ? I guess that would be a duplication with Bundle2's own services ? I can't think of any other way to do that.

What would be the correct way to achieve this ? Many thanks in advance.

I'm running Symfony 3.2.4 by the way.

Comment: https://github.com/mmoreram/symfony-bundle-dependencies

Comment: What makes you think that Bundle2 should not be added to AppKernel?  Assuming that Bundle2 is a real Symfony bundle then that is exactly what you should do which in turn will make any services declared in Bundle2 to be globally accessible.

Comment: @yivi : thanks. It seems that it is what I need, eventhough I really thought core-Symfony would allow something like this. I found [an interesting blog post](http://mmoreram.com/blog/2016/02/09/you-probably-need-bundle-dependencies/) about this.

Comment: @Cerad : thank you for your answer. I thought I shouldn't add Bundle2 to AppKernel, because it is strictly a Bundle1 dependency. My app shouldn't bother with any second level dependency. But I might in the end do that, because I tested it and it works.